# What are possible ways to override User Access Control (UAC) while registering an ActiveX Control?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-vista, uac, activex

In an ASP.NET 2.0 Application, an ActiveX control is used. When user first time access the appliction and he/she did not have that ActiveX registered. Application show a popup to install ActiveX. When user follow the process, ActiveX is registered and application loads the ActiveX to accomplish desired tasks.

In Windows Vista, Win 7 and Win 8, User Access Control (UAC) is prompted to allow to install the ActiveX at very first time. This happens even if user is Administrator too.

What are alternatives to override this UAC component while installing ActiveX ?
Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do this only when installing ActiveX, atleast not without have the actual ActiveX installation to disable UAC, which i doubt is possible.

It is not any good idea to disable UAC in general, as it is their to protect you from running unwanted executables that may harm your computer.

Despite that, then you can find the settings for UAC in the registry:

Go to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Find the DWORD `ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin`

Change the `Valuedata` to `0`

This way you can disable UAC without rebooting.